# Allow only registered users to edit a Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to allow everyone to view my Google Sheets but only users registered with a Google account should be able to edit it, in order to avoid vandalism from anonymous users.

How to do it?

Comment: Registered where? You can share your spreadsheet to specific people and control who can and cannot edit it! It is well [documented here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). If you had something else in mind, please edit to elaborate you quesiton.

Comment: registered with a google account

Comment: So, in other words, _anyone with a Google account_ should be allowed to edit, right?

Comment: Duplicate (although without a solution): [Require User to sign in order to edit a document on Google Drive](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/53548/354)